# Resizing link to be equidistant

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a top tab bar with 4 different tabs. My issue is that due to the fact that the tab titles are not around the same length, they look like they padding is off where the smallest title has a lot of spacing, while everything else is very cramped together (Example of this: https://codepen.io/bigzee/pen/XKLKxG). You can see exactly what I mean when you make the screen browser small (iPhone 5s screen size)

To solve this, I added in left/right spacing (Example here: https://codepen.io/bigzee/pen/OXZXom). However, now when you make the browser small (iPhone 5s screen size) the titles overlap. I tried to use z-index to fix this, but that didn't work. Here's my code with the z-index:

```
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-royal" >
    <div class="tabs" style="position: relative;">
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item" style="color:white; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
            <p class="" style="position: relative; left: 5%;">Top</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item" style="color:white; position: relative; z-index: 2;">
            <p class="" style="position: relative; right: 15%;">Top tab 2</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item" style="color:white; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
            <p class="" style="position: relative; right: 15%;">Top tab 3</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item" style="color:white; position: relative; z-index: 4;">
            <p class="" style="position: relative; right: 15%;">Top tab tab 4</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using rows/columns as well (https://codepen.io/bigzee/pen/PzAzvK) but it was still didn't look right. The code for the rows/columns is below:

```
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-royal" >
    <div class="tabs row" style="">
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item col col-10" style="color:white; min-width: 40px; margin-left: 2%;">
            <p class="" style="">Top</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item  col col-30" style="color:white;">
            <p class="" style="">Top tab 2</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item  col col-30" style="color:white;">
            <p class="" style="">Top tab 3</p>
        </a>
        <a class="bar-royal tab-item  col col-30" style="color:white;">
            <p class="" style="">Top tab tab 4</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice on how I can fix this?

## Solution:

http://codepen.io/bigzee/pen/XKLymE

The accepted answer has the solution on how to fix this. I simply added in a media query to set a max font-size so that on smaller screens the font gets smaller.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top-menu {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  }
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>top</li>
      <li>top tab 2</li>
      <li>top tab 3</li>
      <li>top tab tab 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added display: inline-block here: https://codepen.io/bigzee/pen/akgmBv but if you use chrome inspector to set it to the screen size of an iPhone 6, is the spacing still looks off

Comment: thats a issue of u framework. maybe him give important style to u tabs.

Comment: I'm not using the ul since their styling wasn't carrying over. I applied the inline-block propery to the <a>, still not working :(

Comment: I used your code with a few modifications of my own to get it to work, thanks so much for your help! I'll edit the initial post with a codepen to the fixed version.

Comment: But my answer is not solution?

Comment: My apologizes, I clicked on the wrong answer by mistake. Fixed it now!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the spacing to be consistent, then leaving the `<a>` tags on `width: auto`, applying left and right margins to them, and setting `text-align: center` on the their container is a good bet.

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a>Top</a>
    <a>Top tab 2</a>
    <a>Top tab 3</a>
    <a>Top tab tab 4</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.tabs {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle that has a group of centered links with consistent spacing.

https://jsfiddle.net/reid_horton/53xfjyob/

The percentage based margins help make this example a little more responsive, but if that's not enough, you could also add some media queries.

Side note: unfortunately, you can't have both consistent width *and* consistent space. If each link is the same width, then narrower links are going to have more space around them. If each link has the same space around them, then they can't all be the same width.

Comment: Thanks for the side note, I actually ended up making the font change depending on screen size, and a few other things. Appreciate it!